# NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.Objects Android

Tags: android

In two projects that I've contributed I've had this Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.Objects
```

That because I've implemented `hashCode` and `equals` methods using `Objects` class.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 97 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.image);
    hash = 97 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.car);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final SummaryContent other = (SummaryContent) obj;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.image, other.image)) {
        return false;
    }
    return Objects.equals(this.car, other.car);
}
```

When I compile I don't get error or warnings. Why might it be happening?

Comment: Which version of java you are using?

Comment: To develop I'm using Java 7 (jdk1.7.0_45), but it is happening on my Sony Xperia device on runtime, not at compile time.

Comment: What is the api version of your mobile? It is not available below api level 19

Comment: I'm using a target level 19. My xperia has 4.1.2 android version.

Comment: 4.1.2 is api level 16

Comment: Ah you have all reason, I need work supporting low level api from 19 until 11. Thanks @Goutam

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem in my new game. And i think, it happends, because different mobile manufacturer provide phones with different version of jvm.

My solution of this problem was copying implementation of methos equals from Objects to my project. It dirty, but work:

```
public static boolean equals(Object a, Object b) {
    return (a == b) || (a != null && a.equals(b));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was wrong. My device was android 4.1, which is api level 16 and the class `Objects` is since api level 19.